# What does a bitshift do to sys.stderr?

Tags: python

In a codesnippet I found:

```
import sys

print >> sys.stderr, "hello"
```

Could someone please explain how it works.
I have no Idea how to understand bitshift on a file-like object from a statement?

Thanks

Comment: It is not a bit-shift operator here. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt

Comment: Looks like simple I/O redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> This form is sometimes referred to as “print chevron.” In this form,
>   the first expression after the >> must evaluate to a “file-like”
>   object, specifically an object that has a write() method as described
>   above. With this extended form, the subsequent expressions are printed
>   to this file object. If the first expression evaluates to None, then
>   sys.stdout is used as the file for output.

Basically, a print statement is of the form (verbatim from Docs)

```
print_stmt ::=  "print" ([expression ("," expression)* [","]]
                | ">>" expression [("," expression)+ [","]])
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, did not find this. Looks somewhat pervert anyway (as '<<' and '>>' are declared as bitshift operators, but in this context do completely different things...

Comment: Just interpret them as redirection operators.

Comment: Could you also please explain how to overload this operator on a statement (`print` is a statement), usually one can overload the `__rshift__` function on any object, but on a statement?

Comment: That wouldn't be possible on statements since they are a part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) statement by default writes to `sys.stdout`. If you want `print` to print to another file you have to use the "redirection" syntax using `>>`.